# Build path exception in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I have an android project built in eclipse and i set a java project as the required project on 
the build path. The strange problem here is when i run the android project I would found i go into a class which is not belong to the java project i specified as the required project on the build path, instead, it's a class has the same name but located in a different project I've never linked to the android project. I was totally confused by this problem, having no clues at all. How can eclipse find and run a class without in the build path?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)Main.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
    }
```

Use this code in Main class to find out from which locations ClassLoader is picking the dependency.